# Django - Docker - The Application Default Credentials are not available

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docker, google-cloud-platform

I would like to use Google Cloud SDK with Django project in Docker container. Let's assume that I would like to use

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
```

When I install `google-cloud` using `requirements.txt` file I get error shown below. On my local machine without container it works properly. Does anyone have an idea how can I solve this?

> django_1 | oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are
>   available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the
>   environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined
>   pointing to a file defining the credentials. See
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

**UPDATE**
I work on MacBook and I found on [this website](http://blog.ctaggart.com/2016/11/pass-google-application-default.html) this:

```
docker run --rm -it -v ~/.config/gcloud:/.config/gcloud google/cloud-sdk
```

At this moment I get errors shown below. Any ideas how can I solve this?

```
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
django_1  |     response = get_response(request)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
django_1  |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
django_1  |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
django_1  |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
django_1  |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
django_1  |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
django_1  |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
django_1  |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/code/backend/views.py", line 23, in get
django_1  |     client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/gapic/vision/v1/image_annotator_client.py", line 147, in __init__
django_1  |     ssl_credentials=ssl_credentials)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/grpc.py", line 106, in create_stub
django_1  |     credentials = _grpc_google_auth.get_default_credentials(scopes)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/_grpc_google_auth.py", line 62, in get_default_credentials
django_1  |     credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 282, in default
django_1  |     raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
django_1  | google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or
django_1  | explicitly create credential and re-run the application. For more
django_1  | information, please see
django_1  | https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.
```

Comment: Try this `docker run -e "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" --rm -it -v ~/.config/gcloud:/.config/gcloud google/cloud-sdk`

Comment: @TarunLalwani After using your command there is `root@4271b8a28802:/#` and still the same error.

Comment: can you run `env` on your mac and post all `google` related environment variables? Make any value that need to be private replaced by dummy value.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Did you mean information that I added to the updated question?

Comment: You need to use service account https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#generating-a-private-key. Read this https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/auth.html

Comment: @TarunLalwani I did it on my local machine and it is working properly. I have to do it also in container for instance in `docker exec -ti project_django_1 /bin/bash`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154072/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-john-smith).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the you are mounting the folder to `/` instead of `/root/` where the config will be checked for

change

```
docker run --rm -it -v ~/.config/gcloud:/.config/gcloud google/cloud-sdk
```

to

```
docker run --rm -it -v ~/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud google/cloud-sdk
```

If you are use docker-compose then add it to the yaml of the particular server

```
volumes:
  - ~/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud
```